Proof check: The existence of algebraic closure
Problem: Every field $F$ has an algebraic closure.
I have seen a proof by Artin,which shows there is an algebraically closed   field containing $F$ first.But it is so elegant that it's hard to think.
Inspired by Ash, I try to use well-ordering principle and transfinite induction to prove it directly.
My attempt：
Well order $F\left[ x \right]$,
set $J = \Big\{ {f \in F\left[ x \right]: \text{there is a smallest field } K_f \text{ containing all  roots of each } g\in{S_f} \cup \left\{ f \right\},F \subseteq {K_f} } \Big\}$
Assume that ${S_f} \subseteq J$.
Case1:$f$ has predecessor $g$.
$f \in F\left[ x \right] \subseteq {K_g}\left[ x \right]$, then there is an extension $L$ of $K_g$ such that $L$ is a splitting field for $f$.
Suppose $C$ is an arbitrary extension of $F$,containing all roots of polynomials in ${S_f} \cup \left\{ f \right\}$.
Then by definition of $K_g$,$K_g \subseteq C $. Moreover, we can identify $f$ as an element of $K_g[x]$, $f$ splits over $C$.
Since $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K_g$,we have $L \subseteq C$, so $L$ is just the $K_f$ as desired.
Case2:$f$ has no predecessor.
Given $g,h \in S_f$ distinct, suppose $g<h$, then $K_h$ contains all roots of
polynomials in ${S_g} \cup \left\{ g \right\}$, by the minimality of $K_g$, $K_g \subseteq K_h$, so that $\bigcup_{g \in {S_f}} {K_g}$ is a field, we denote $\bigcup_{g \in {S_f}} {K_g}$ by $U$.
Likewise, there is an extension $L$ of $U$,s.t. $L$ is a splitting field for $f$.
Suppose $C$ is an arbitrary extension of $F$,containing all roots of polynomials in ${S_f} \cup \left\{ f \right\}$.
Obviously, for each $g \in S_f$, $K_g \subseteq C$, hence $U \subseteq C$.
Again, by $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $U$ and $f$ splits over $C$,we can deduce that $L \subseteq C$.
So that in both cases, $L$ is just the $K_f$ as desired, i.e. $f \in J $.
By transfinite induction $F[x]=J$.
Then $\bigcup_{f \in F\left[ x \right]} {K_f}$ is a field that every polynomial over $F$ splits completely over it, i.e. $\bigcup_{f \in F\left[ x \right]} {K_f}$ is the algebraic closure of $F$.
Something that confuses me:
In case2,I use the minimality of $K_g$ to obtain "$K_g \subseteq K_h$",but actually $K_h$ only contains an isomorphic copy of $K_g$,so the step of taking union is not rigorous.
Does it possible to solve this problem without taking $F$ into an algebraically closed field?
Since I am a beginner in learning abstract algebra, I'm not sure if there is anything wrong with my proof. Anyone can help me？I would appreciate it.

What is the set $S_f$?

the section of $F[x]$ by $f$@schiepy

What does that mean?

${S_f} = \left{ {g \in F\left[ x \right]:g < f} \right}$@schiepy

And you take any well-ordering of the set $F[x]$ I guess? Then can you explain what "Assume $S_f\subseteq J$" means? What is $f$? Why can you make that assumption?

I think it is almost impossible to define a natural order such that $F[x]$ is well ordered,since  $F[x]$ may be uncountable. So I apply Zermelo’s well-ordering principle here.@schiepy

Since $F[x]$ may not be countable,so the usual mathematical induction fails.So I use transfinite induction here,"Assume $S_f  \subseteq J$"  to prove $f \in J$ recusively. I'm guessing you might not be familiar with this method.@schiepy

So two things: The first is, if you look for a proof verification, you should tag it and then specify which part in the proof you feel unsure about and why. The second thing is that you kind of need a field above all the other fields to be rigorous because the fields $K_f$ for different $f$ could be very different objects, e.g. matrices, elements in quotient rings (i.e. cosets), ... You could work around that but that needs a lot of formal stuff I think.

Thanks schiepy.You pointed out what was bothering me.Suppose $g<h$,we can only say that $K_h$ contains an isomorphic copy of $K_g$,so it fails to take union of them.I'll add it later.This is the first time I've asked a question, thanks again for the advice!@schiepy

No worries, I look forward to your edits.
